# jquery click() problem, how to?

Tags: jquery, click

i have this setup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#click_me_link").click(function () {
      $("#link_more").show("slow");
   });
});
</script>

<div id="click_me_link"><img src="/images/banner_bottom.png"></div>
<div id="link_more" style="width: 530px; height: 66px; display: none;">
   test
</div>
```

if i click on the `click_me_link` it wont display the hidden div. if i run `$("#link_more").show("slow");` in the console it works

any idea?
thanks
semicolon fixed, still doesn't work

Comment: Check to see if there is an error in your javascript.

Comment: anything on the console?

Comment: You missed a semicolon between the height and display properties in the link_more's style. Does that fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working here http://jsfiddle.net/imoda/eXPW5/

You're missing a `;` after the height property

```
<div id="link_more" style="width: 530px; height: 66px display: none;">
```

Not sure if that's causing your problem as I can't seem to replicate it, but it's no doubt something to fix.

Comment: There's no way that would be the answer. See my comment on John Kalberer's answer. Missing a semicolon would prevent the DIV from being hidden. It would not prevent it from being shown upon a click event. It would cause the exact opposite of the problem stated!

Comment: I agree.  My guess is that there are other things at play that are having some sort of effect.  Going off what OP has provided, this doesn't fix what he's talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah the issue is your css in link_more.  You are missing a semicolon.  It needs to be this:

```
width: 530px; height: 66px; display: none;
```

Anyway, you probably want to make click_me_link an anchor instead of a div and use e.preventDefault() inside your click event.

Comment: Actually, that wouldn't prevent the hidden div from showing. It would prevent it from being hidden in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, that was the only issue I found when I moved it to jsfiddle.  I am guessing the overall cause must be a browser issue.

Comment: +1 For saying you should wrap the image in an anchor tag. This will make the web page more accessibility friendly for screen readers and any browser with JavaScript disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a semi-colon after "66px". Other than that, your example is working for me.

Here is a working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mm9AQ/